# Numpy optimise mesh edges length calculation

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, numpy

*To improve my very rudimentary numpy knowledge am going to ask a number of optimise my numpy questions here on BSE*

Can find the length of each edge in a mesh using

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
nverts = len(me.vertices)
nedges = len(me.edges)
#nloops = len(me.loops)

vcoords = np.empty(3 * nverts)
me.vertices.foreach_get("co", vcoords)
edges = np.zeros(2 * nedges, dtype=np.int32)
me.edges.foreach_get("vertices", edges)

vcoords3d = vcoords.reshape((-1, 3))
a, b = edges.reshape((-1, 2)).T

edge_lengths = np.linalg.norm(
        vcoords3d[a] - vcoords3d[b],
        axis=1,
        )
        
print(edge_lengths)
```

Output for default cube, (lengths in mesh.edges index order)

```
[2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
```

what `numpy` voodoo magic can optimize this further?

Comment: Just out of interest, where do you have a sneaky feeling there _might_ be an optimisation?

Comment: Sorry... I should be more liberal with my emoticons. ( :) )

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use the `.calc_length()` function on the edge to get it's length, unless you strictly want to use numpy for the calculations.

Comment: The reason to use numpy is performance. Your solution is likely to be much slower if a large number of edges is considered.